# Developing the utility classes, should I provide the non-mutable API for the usage with frameworks like React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, immutability, react-state

Currently, I am developing the `DateWithoutTime` class.
For this question, it is important that this class has private fields which being mutated by the public methods.

```js
this.state.dateWithoutTimeInstance.shiftBySpecificDaysCount({
  daysCount: 5,
  toFuture: true
});
```

Although I have omitted some parts of the original the class, the code listing is still too long, so I'll append it to the end of the question.

In the frameworks like React we can not mutate the object.
So, I assume, in the React, instead of above code it is required to create the new variable like based on the old variable like:

```
let updatedDateWithoutTimeInstance: DateWithoutTime = new DateWithoutTime({
  year: this.state.dateWithoutTimeInstance.year,
  monthNumber__numerationFrom1: this.state.dateWithoutTimeInstance.monthNumber__numerationFrom1,
  dayOfMonth: this.state.dateWithoutTimeInstance.dayOfMonth
});

updatedDateWithoutTimeInstance.shiftBySpecificDaysCount({
  daysCount: 5,
  toFuture: true
});

this.setState((state) => {
  return { dateWithoutTimeInstance: updatedDateWithoutTimeInstance };
});
```

Can we write

```
this.state.dateWithoutTimeInstance.shiftBySpecificDaysCount({
  daysCount: 5,
  toFuture: true
});
```

in React? If no, it's required to provide the method for the non-mutable updating like:

```js
this.setState((state) => {
  return { 
  // returns new instance
dateWithoutTimeInstance: 
this.state.dateWithoutTimeInstance.shiftBySpecificDaysCountImmutably({
  daysCount: 5,
  toFuture: true
});};
});
```

### Appendix: partial listing of the "DateWithoutTime" class

```js
import type {
  MonthsNames
} from `@yamato-daiwa/ex-extensions`

import {
    DaysOfWeek,
    Logger,
    InvalidParameterValueError,
    getISO8601StringWithoutTimePart,
    getMonthNameByNumber,
    shiftDateBySpecificDaysCount,
    isNumber,
    isString,
    getMonthNumberByName
} from `@yamato-daiwa/ex-extensions`


class DateWithoutTime {

  protected _nativeDateObject!: Date;

  protected _year!: number;

  protected _monthName!: MonthsNames;
  protected _monthNumber__numerationFrom0!: number;
  protected _monthNumber__numerationFrom1!: number;
  protected _monthNumber__numerationFrom1__2Digits!: string;

  protected _dayOfMonth!: number;
  protected _dayOfMonth__2Digits!: string;

  protected _dayOfWeek!: DaysOfWeek;
  protected _dayOfWeekNumber__numerationFrom0AsSunday!: number;
  protected _dayOfWeekNumber__numerationFrom1AsSunday!: number;
  protected _dayOfWeekNumber__numerationFrom1AsSunday__2Digits!: string;


  public constructor(rawDateTime: number | string | Date | DateWithoutTime.DateDefinition) {

    try {

      if (isNumber(rawDateTime) || isString(rawDateTime) || rawDateTime instanceof Date) {
        this.nativeDateObject = new Date(rawDateTime);
      } else {
        this.nativeDateObject = DateWithoutTime.dateDefinitionToNativeDateObject(rawDateTime);
      }


    } catch (error: unknown) {

      Logger.throwErrorAndLog({
        errorInstance: new InvalidParameterValueError({
          parameterName: "rawDateTime",
          parameterNumber: 1
        }),
        title: InvalidParameterValueError.localization.defaultTitle,
        occurrenceLocation: "DateWithoutTime.constructor(rawDateTime)",
        wrappableError: error
      });

    }

  }


  public shiftBySpecificDaysCount(
    namedParameters: Readonly<
      { daysCount: number; } &
      (
        {
          toFuture: true;
          toPast?: undefined;
        } |
        {
          toPast: true;
          toFuture?: undefined;
        }
      )
    >
  ): this {

    this.nativeDateObject = shiftDateBySpecificDaysCount({
      initialDate: this._nativeDateObject,
      dayCount: namedParameters.daysCount,
      ...namedParameters.toFuture === true ? { toFuture: true } : { toPast: true }
    });

    return this;

  }


  public get year(): number { return this._year; }
  public get monthName(): MonthsNames { return this._monthName; }
  
  // Other getters...

  public get nativeDateObject(): Date { return this._nativeDateObject; }
  protected set nativeDateObject(value: Date) {

    this._nativeDateObject = value;

    this._year = this._nativeDateObject.getFullYear();

    this._monthNumber__numerationFrom0 = this._nativeDateObject.getMonth();
    this._monthNumber__numerationFrom1 = this._monthNumber__numerationFrom0 + 1;
    this._monthNumber__numerationFrom1__2Digits = this._monthNumber__numerationFrom1.toString().padStart(2, "0");

    this._monthName = getMonthNameByNumber({ targetMonthNumber: this._monthNumber__numerationFrom1, numerationFrom: 1 });

    this._dayOfMonth = this._nativeDateObject.getDate();
    this._dayOfMonth__2Digits = this._dayOfMonth.toString().padStart(2, "0");

    this._dayOfWeekNumber__numerationFrom0AsSunday = this._nativeDateObject.getDay();
    this._dayOfWeekNumber__numerationFrom1AsSunday = this._dayOfWeekNumber__numerationFrom0AsSunday + 1;
    this._dayOfWeekNumber__numerationFrom1AsSunday__2Digits =
        this._dayOfWeekNumber__numerationFrom1AsSunday.toString().padStart(2, "0");

    switch (this._dayOfWeekNumber__numerationFrom1AsSunday) {
      case 1: { this._dayOfWeek = DaysOfWeek.sunday; break; }
      case 2: { this._dayOfWeek = DaysOfWeek.monday; break; }
      case 3: { this._dayOfWeek = DaysOfWeek.tuesday; break; }
      case 4: { this._dayOfWeek = DaysOfWeek.wednesday; break; }
      case 5: { this._dayOfWeek = DaysOfWeek.thursday; break; }
      case 6: { this._dayOfWeek = DaysOfWeek.friday; break; }
      default: { this._dayOfWeek = DaysOfWeek.saturday; }
    }

  }


  private static dateDefinitionToNativeDateObject(rawDateTime: Readonly<DateWithoutTime.DateDefinition>): Date {
    return new Date(
      rawDateTime.year,
      ((): number => {

        if ("monthName" in rawDateTime) {
          return getMonthNumberByName({
            targetMonthName: rawDateTime.monthName,
            numerationFrom: 0
          });
        }

        return "monthNumber__numerationFrom1" in rawDateTime ?
            rawDateTime.monthNumber__numerationFrom1 - 1 : rawDateTime.monthNumber__numerationFrom0;

      })(),
      rawDateTime.dayOfMonth
    );
  }

}


namespace DateWithoutTime {

  export type DateDefinition =
    {
      year: number;
      dayOfMonth: number;
    } &
    (
      { monthName: MonthsNames; } |
      { monthNumber__numerationFrom0: number; } |
      { monthNumber__numerationFrom1: number; }
    );

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can we write
>
> ```
> this.state.dateWithoutTimeInstance.shiftBySpecificDaysCount({
>  daysCount: 5,
>  toFuture: true
> });
>
> in React?
> ```

No (or rather, you can *write* it, but it won't work correctly). React state members must be treated as though they were immutable. From [the documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#do-not-modify-state-directly):

> **Do Not Modify State Directly**
>
> For example, this will not re-render a component:
>
> ```
> // Wrong
> this.state.comment = 'Hello';
> ```
>
> Instead, use `setState()`:
>
> ```
> // Correct
> this.setState({comment: 'Hello'});
> ```

(And this is covered in various other places.) You need to *replace* the state member with a new instance with the updated state.

Here's an example of mutating a state object. Notice that the component doesn't re-render:

```js
class Example extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            now: new Date(),
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.timer = setInterval(() => {
            // WRONG, mutating state in place
            this.state.now.setSeconds(this.state.now.getSeconds() + 1);
            // This would also be wrong:
            // this.setState(({ now }) => {
            //     // WRONG, mutating state in place
            //     now.setSeconds(now.getSeconds() + 1);
            //     return { now };
            // });
        }, 1000);
    }

    render() {
        return <div>Now: {this.state.now.toISOString()}</div>;
    }
}

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<Example />);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Here is is written correctly (but more verbosely than one normally would, just for clarity):

```js
class Example extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            now: new Date(),
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.timer = setInterval(() => {
            // RIGHT, replacing with a new object
            this.setState(({now}) => {
                const updated = new Date(now);
                updated.setSeconds(updated.getSeconds() + 1)
                return {
                    now: updated,
                };
            });
        }, 1000);
    }

    render() {
        return <div>Now: {this.state.now.toISOString()}</div>;
    }
}

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<Example />);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```